# Where does the ActiveX control GUID for Internet Explorer web browser come from?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, activex

I've noticed that a few ActiveX-based webviews leveraging web browser control through the following GUID

```
Web Browswer Control - 8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2
```

that GUID shows up in some Microsoft pages such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc750862(v=technet.10)), and it also shows up in a few StackOverflow questions.  However, I wasn't able to find the source of truth regarding that GUID and also any reference ho how to use it.

With that in mind, does anyone know where the web browser control GUID come from?  And is there any guide on how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

It is `CLSID_WebBrowser` which is a COM class that implements the [IWebBrowser2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752127(v=vs.85)) interface. This is essentially Internet Explorer.

The definition is in ExDisp.Idl in the Windows SDK.

To use it, call `CoCreateInstance` like you would on any other COM object. In something higher level like Visual Basic or WSH, use [`Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85)).

See also:

- [Embed an HTML control in your own window using plain C](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3365/Embed-an-HTML-control-in-your-own-window-using-pla)